# Training and Testing LSTM

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, python, lstm

I've been reading this [article about multivariate LSTM](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/). I'm still a beginner so my questions might be silly.

As far as I understand, we need to divide the data set on training and testing/validation.

In this part of the code, it said that it will predict the next step of pollution based on the previous step only using "**the series_to_supervised()**" function!

I thought that once the model is trained we don't need to define how many inputs (here is n_in=1 in the first example and n_in=3 in the second one), but here, it says that we predict the next value of pollution based on the the previous step value only !! Any explanation ??

**The series_to_supervised() function :**

```
# convert series to supervised learning
def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    df = DataFrame(data)
    cols, names = list(), list()
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
        names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
    for i in range(0, n_out):
        cols.append(df.shift(-i))
        if i == 0:
            names += [('var%d(t)' % (j+1)) for j in range(n_vars)]
        else:
            names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # put it all together
    agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
    agg.columns = names
    # drop rows with NaN values
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    return agg
```

**The code**:

```
# load dataset
dataset = read_csv('pollution.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
values = dataset.values
# integer encode direction
encoder = LabelEncoder()
values[:,4] = encoder.fit_transform(values[:,4])
# ensure all data is float
values = values.astype('float32')
# normalize features
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(values)
# frame as supervised learning
reframed = series_to_supervised(scaled, 1, 1)
# drop columns we don't want to predict
reframed.drop(reframed.columns[[9,10,11,12,13,14,15]], axis=1, inplace=True)
print(reframed.head())
```